# iOS app with interface reminiscent of Finder's column view

Tags: ios

How would I go about making a simple iOS app that simply has to display "data sheets" (just text documents basically) in a way reminiscent of OS X's Finder's Column View?

I want the interface to present a list of Manufacturers. I select one and then a bunch of Models made by that Manufacturer come up. I select one and finally I'm presented with Years. I select a Year and then I am shown a list of all variants of that Model made in that Year. When I press one of these Models I'm shown a textual data sheet for that model.

I mean, I don't even know whether to start this as a Master-Detail Application (although that sort of looks like it might work), a Page-Based Application, a Single View Application or a Tabbed Application...

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. UITableView it is!

Comment: Good luck, don't hesitate to ask other specific questions as new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you will nee dto get in to `UITableView`.

It's fairly simple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html

https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Be sure to work 100% using storyboard, and Swift. In answer to your final question simpy start it as a single view app.

Interestingly, once you get good one of the toughest and most expert-level skills in iOS is dynamic height cells in table views.  [Example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift) of that.